# Tools to test a BigData Pipeline end to end?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, bigdata

I have this pipeline: Webserver+rsyslog->Kafka->Logstash->ElasticSearch->Kibana

I have found these tools to help test my pipeline:

1. Generate webserver load by spinning up jmeter EC2 instances with [jmeter-ec2](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2)
2. Generate load on Kafka and help graph throughput with [Sangrenel](https://github.com/jamiealquiza/sangrenel)

I am wondering if anyone had any other suggestions for testing components or end-to-end testing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! I am looking for something similar but may settle on a simple home solution.

1. Set up Storm cluster with bolts writing data to Kafka. One thing to watch out for is the id/key so your messages are distributed across multiple partitions. The reason for Storm is to have distributed set of publishers. As alternative to Storm, you can have multiple producers with lets say KafkaAppender
2. Once you know your Kafka performance, connect Logstash to loaded topic and let it drain as fast as possible. You may find some useful information with KafkaManager or connecting to JMX (many tools for that)
3. Simplest way to monitor Elastic is Marvel
4. Performance of Kibana depends on amount of data your query returns but the smallest interval is still 5 sec.

In my experience, logstash performance will depend on data size and grok complexity. The performance of Elastic is mostly cluster size, shard/template configuration. The fastest component in your setup will always be Kafka (bounded by ack and Zookeeper settings)

Also, if you control data generation, you may compare time of record generated vs @timestamp of logstash and measure lagging.